# ubuntu 12.04 does not detect already installed windows 7

Tags: installation

I have already installed windows 7 ultimate. When i tried to install ubuntu 12.04, installer didn't detect windows even i have only two  primary and two logical partition on windows  when i goes through try ubuntu and use command    " os-prober" it shows output like as

```
 unshare failed: Operation not permitted
ERROR: you must be root
ERROR: you must be root
ERROR: you must be root
ERROR: you must be root
ERROR: you must be root
ERROR: you must be root
mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/lib/os-prober/mount': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/lib/os-prober/mount': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/lib/os-prober/mount': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/lib/os-prober/mount': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/lib/os-prober/mount': Permission denied"
```

Please help me. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

**sudo** os-prober, but maybe **sudo** update-grub(*2*)